# How did the rangers make it home after the train crash?

Tags: power-rangers, power-rangers-2017

After the train crash they all woke up at home, unharmed. I don't have an issue with them surviving the train crash, it was probably the power coins, but I don't believe that the power coins brought them home. Maybe they were going to explain it in the sequel.

Comment: @Ben From the OP: "*I don't have an issue with them surviving the train crash, it was probably the power coins, but I don't believe that the power coins brought them home.*" Old question is specifically about survival; this one is specifically *not* about survival but getting home.

Comment: @Randal'Thor good point. I have retracted my vtc

Answer (score 2):

### The Power Coins activate the Ranger's Teleportation Powers.

In the original series, the Power Coins not only allowed them to transform into the Power Rangers, and protect them, they were also able to [teleport](https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Teleportation) wherever they needed to be.

The YouTuber [DabRanger](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuuTEqWxSzsNX0UMCu32-2Q) managed to find this in the movie. After the train crash, you can faintly see flashes of yellow and blue and pink.

This was never clearly explained in the movie, since there as no other instances of teleportation (insinuated or otherwise) anywhere else in the movie, making this easy to miss and a potential plot hole without any explanation or prior knowledge of the Power Ranger's abilities.